# Do only Pativratra wives accompany their husbands in heaven ? Do non-Pativratas also accompany the husband in afterlife?

Tags: marriage, afterlife, heaven, wife, pativrata

It is quite well known that if a woman is Pativrata , she will take her husband to heaven along with herself. That is Pativrata wife will accompany the husband in heaven or afterlife.

My question is - Do non-Pativrata women also accompany the husbands in afterlife ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Do non-Pativrata women also accompany the husbands in afterlife ?*

No. See the following verses:

> Manu Smriti 5.160. A virtuous wife who after the death of her husband
> constantly remains chaste, reaches heaven, though she have no son,
> just like those chaste men.
>
> 5.161. But a woman who from a desire to have offspring violates her duty towards her (deceased) husband, brings on herself disgrace in
> this world, **and loses her place with her husband (in heaven)**

Here verse 160 talks about Pativratas and 161 about non-Pativratas.