# Do husband and wife get Moksha/heaven/hell or any other fate in afterlife together?

Tags: marriage, wife, husband

Do husband and wife meet the same fate in afterlife , be it heaven , hell or Moksha ?

Comment: [Related 1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/do-husband-and-wife-go-to-heaven-or-hell-together) [Related 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/do-only-pativratra-wives-accompany-their-husbands-in-heaven-do-non-pativratas?rq=1)